# How to chose the close case layout for the mass close button in a list view

Tags: page-layout

When users are viewing the cases that are assigned to a certain queue, they use that queues list view, and see these buttons:

[image: List View Buttons]

It is my intention that they should be able to use the close button on that list view shown above in order to mass close cases. However, I need to have a particular *close case layout* appear when I press that button, and do not not where I configure this from.

How do I assign the close case page layout that I want to appear when pressing the mass close button in the case list view?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit / create new case buttons in `Setup -> Customize -> Cases -> Buttons and Links`

I see that you've made 'close case layout' italic, im not sure if that means you've got an s-control or vf page your using.

If its an s-control you can just edit the existing Close button and set it to use your s-control.

If you've got a VF page you will need to create a new custom button. You can then use the settings:

- Display Type: List Button
- Content Source: Visualforce Page
- Content:

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not using an s-control or a visualforce page. Cases have a special Close Case Layout as well as the normal Case Page Layout. I was hoping that I would be able to assign the correct Close Case Layout when the Close button is pressed from the list view.

Comment: @Joe The standard Close case layout is for closing single cases and wont be able to deal with multiple cases which is why its not appearing for you to use. I think you will have to write your own VF page that mimics this screens layout but is coded to deal with multiple cases